# Upgrade path for NEXUS 5672UP

Tags: cisco-nx-os, os-upgrade-procedure

It's the first Nexus family switch im going to upgrade. Currently I've this type of model:

```
Mod Ports Module-Type Model Status
--- ----- ----------------------------------- ---------------------- ------------
1 48 Nexus 5672UP Supervisor N5K-C5672UP-SUP active *
2 6 Nexus 6xQSFP Ethernet Module N5K-C5672UP-M6Q ok

Mod Sw Hw World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)
--- -------------- ------ ----------------------------------------------------
1 7.0(8)N1(1) 1.0 --
2 7.0(8)N1(1) 1.0 --
```

I did not found any upgrade path generator, but from the release notes i see - that first i need to go to > 7.1.4.N1.(1) and after that I can upgrade to > 7.3(8)N1(1).

So the whole path is like this: 7.0(8)N1(1) (Current) > 7.1.4.N1.(1) > 7.3(8)N1(1)

The upgrade itself will be with `install all kickstart bootflash:xxx.bin system bootflash:xxx.bin` commands.

Maybe you have some recommendations ? I heard that it's possible to lose some config, but if i'm following the upgrade path - this shouldnt be the case.

Also - after upgrade - do i need to add boot commands to running config to make the system boot new images ? or it should be done automatically ? Thanks

Comment: You researched the recommended the upgrade path which is a critical step.  I always recommend comparing configurations between upgrades as a sanity check.  Check each release notes for caveats which may pertain to your scenario and changes in default behavior.

Comment: If you can upgrade, then you have the ability to call Cisco TAC to get specific step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Perhaps his org does, but not necessarily the OP. (my employer has (had) lots of a contracts with many vendors, but that doesn't mean *I* get to talk directly with them.) Also, there are many levels of smartnet. I would dial back my go-ask-the-vendor finger, or you'll be spending a lot of your time sending people to Cisco, Juniper, Arista, etc.

Comment: I'm familiar with the process for n3k's. I'd have to look up the release notes for the n5k's. There is a specific sequence because various bits of firmware need to be updated along the way.

Comment: thanks. The only thing i'm curious is this statement on interim version release notes: [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/upgrade/714_N1_1/n5500_upgrade_downgrade_714_n1_1.html) ` If you want to upgrade from a release on Cisco NX-OS release 7.1 train or earlier, you must first upgrade to Cisco NX-OS release 7.1(4)N1(1) and then to 7.3(2)N1(1). If you want to upgrade from a release on Cisco NX-OS release 7.2 train, you must first upgrade to Cisco NX-OS release 7.2(1)N1(1) and then to 7.3(2)N1(1).` But on the newest version it doesnt mention anything..